# Is there a way to statically evaluate the argument of a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a tool (built with node.js) to modify some values of a web page for each request.

As an example, if my html document as an element like this:

```
<div id="mydiv"> This is a div </div>
```

My tool will updated it to be something like this in a given moment:

```
<div id="aka67213h82h7"> This is a div </div>
```

The value is going to be always different. It's random. My objective is to prevent other people from using this attributes to tamper or extract information from my web page.

Now, to keep everything working I need to update also CSS files and JS files. I am assuming a website will only have HTML, CSS and JavaScript code. CSS files are no trouble, and I am handling them. But JS scripts are a different story..

If I have this line of code:

```
var element = document.getElementById("mydiv");
```

I want to update that line and change `"mydiv"` to `"aka67213h82h7"`. This is possible to do and I am doing this. But, if we rewrite the code to:

```
var idOfElement = "mydiv";
var element = document.getElementById(idOfElement);
```

The only thing I can extract is that `idOfElement` is a variable that contains the value I want to update. This is just a simple example since the argument could be also `performFunction()` and so on..

If the argument of the a function like `getElementById()` is a Literal I am able to do what I want. But if it is an Identifier or a Binary Expression, etc, this becomes my problem. So, how can I be certain of the value of these type of arguments in that moment?

Comment: Is it always different, or is it random? The two are not mutually exclusive

Comment: *My objective is to prevent other people from using this attributes to tamper or extract information from my web page.* I really cannot understand your goal here. If you are displaying a webpage, you are already exposing all the info of said page. Having random `id` doesn't really prevent anything... except for bots maybe?

Comment: If your tool can update an HTML file, can't it just update the JS file as well?

Comment: "*My objective is to prevent other people from using this attributes to tamper*" - you cannot. The only tamperproof website is no website. See, if you found a way to locate the element with your script, why wouldn't anyone else?

Comment: "*My objective is to prevent […] extract information from my web page.*" - a website that reveals no information is useless. It won't be displayed in a browser, it won't be found by search engines, it won't be visited by any users. Don't hurt accessibility!

Comment: _"I am working on a tool (built with node.js) to modify some values of a web page for each request."_ You could possibly use a web worker to modify the `id` or other attributes of elements every 1 second or less, without reloading page, though this would still allow the entire `html` `document` to be saved and modified by user. _"My objective is to prevent other people from using this attributes to tamper or extract information from my web page"_ Another option would be to serve and display the `html` `document` as an image, where `id` of elements would not matter.

Comment: each time my server sends the html page, he is calculating new random values for ids and other attributes. Yes Chris, is to prevent automated attacks. Has I said, I can parse a JS script and find the arguments but no the value. I mean, it can be a string, the name of a variable, a function call, ... but what I needed was always the value... otherwise, statically I can't change it right now

Comment: You can create an array or object containing all of the randomly generated `id`s on page, iterate the list and change `id`s in order; remove `<script>` elements and write new `<script>` elements having changed values

Comment: if i have this `document.getElementById("mydiv")` it will be changed to this `document.getElementById("aka67213h82h7")`. But if I have  `document.getElementById(varName)` I cannot change anything.. and that's what I wanted

Comment: You can use `String.prototype.replace()` to replace `.textContent` of `<script>` elements to new `id`, or variable name, if you have current `id` or variable name and new `id` or variable name to change to. Or simply remove the `<script>` node and insert a new `<script>` node into `document` having replaced content. Though, again, this will not prevent user from modifying `document`. If page is not interactive, you can render `html` as an `<img>`, or draw `html` onto a `<canvas>` element, then serve `document` as a single `<canvas>` element

Comment: Let me try to explain it better. Imagine this: `document.getElementById(argument)`. Now, `argument` can be a Literal, an Identifier, a Binary Expression, etc.. If it is a Literal, good for me. Easy to replace. If its not, I cannot replace because I don't know the what is the value to replace

Comment: _"cannot replace because I don't know the what is the value to replace"_ Why would you not know what the value is to replace? Do you not store the random `id` before serving the `document`?

Comment: Yes I know the random `id` but I don't know what is the "old" one... The website and my tool are independent. Let's say its your website. My tool would be a black box that you setup in your server that should do all the updates without knowing what ids you have chosen

Comment: @rydeen _"Yes I know the random id but I don't know what is the "old" one..."_ Not following. You should be able to know what old `id` is by storing the `id` linearly, that is, at each encounter of a variable that is changed push the changed `id` to an array, replace old `id` in array with new value; keep reference to array with old `id`'s

Comment: if its your code and I don't read your code, I will not know.. Only my tool will look to your code. That's why I don't know the old `id`

Comment: _"Only my tool will look to your code. That's why I don't know the old id"_ ? Yes, you would be able to know that old `id`. If `js` uses `document.getElementById("_id")`, and at server if `document.getElementById("_id")` does not return `null` , the element exists in `DOM`; store that old `id` in an array?

Comment: @rydeen: have you ever heard about templating?

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. In cases of `document.getElementById(somevar)`, you don't need to change that code, you only need to change `var somevar = 'theid';`.

Comment: @KevinB, that's right. But `somevar` can be changed during the execution, before being used in `document.getElementById(somevar)`. Or `somevar` can be defined in a different script. So I cannot assume that I can update the value directly in is declaration

Comment: so... take the varname and replace it with your string? but that could cause even more problems, because you then have to follow variable scope and only change it where it references the original variable, and not where that same var name might be re-used as a param somewhere. There won't be an easy solution to that, because at that point you're talking about more than find/replace, you'd actually have to parse the javascript and understand what it is doing.

Comment: And then you have to think about cases where that id value is stored as an object property. I think you're barking up the wrong tree. Even if you managed to get this working, users can still take the id in the input and find it within the javascript to do with as they please.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you can update your id with:

```
elements.id = 'randomValue';
```

Comment: But any human with  average Prog.Skills knows when he is ask for an email adress and checks your id for the input and its called "akkasdasd" knows what it used for.

Comment: No. My problem is not "How to change the id of an element".. HTML was just to give context to my question and id was an example.

Comment: _"No. My problem is not "How to change the id of an element"."_ What is actual issue? Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Comment: ok, you wrote your website and you know the id for whatever you want to access. Now, you run my tool on your server, before sending your HTML document. Automatically, I will change you HTML and CSS, but right now I cannot say your JS scripts will still work because if you are accessing you ids like this `getElementById("thisId")` is not the same thing as if you are accessing like `var id = "thisId"'; getElementById(id)`. Statically, I want to know the value of that variable that should be the "old" name for your ids

Comment: @rydeen _"Now, you run my tool on your server, before sending your HTML document."_ What is the purpose of tool? What is expected result of changing variable values? At any point a viewer can save the `html` `document` and match variables at `js` to `id` at `html`

Comment: I want to make the website somehow polymorphic so that automated tools aren't able to locate specific elements on a website. An automated tool will always be looking for something like `div#mydiv`. I am changing the value of `id` for each refresh, so it will be always different, hence stopping the attack. But to keep the website working, I need to make sure the scripts working with `ids` are not broken

Comment: I did a JS-Bin http://jsbin.com/jifiyexusa/edit?html,js,console,output and booth versions of of get element are working the same .                 You can build up an array with old, new pairs at the start .

Comment: @rydeen _" I need to make sure the scripts working with ids are not broken"_ When tool initially runs the `id`s in `js` would match the `id`s in `html`, yes? In linear fashion when an `id` is encountered in `js` and that `id` successfully returns a `DOM` element at server, add old `id` to an array, change id at `js`, `html`

Comment: @Opaldes, I changed you example to what I want. http://jsbin.com/velekofiqe/1/edit?html,js,console,output. In the HTML `id="test"` became something else. Now, JS is broken. I want to update JS automatically, but how?

Comment: @rydeen Example at http://jsbin.com/velekofiqe/1/edit?html,js,console,output appears to change `id` at `html` before changing `js`? You could check if each `id` at `js` returns a `DOM` element, then for each match, adjust `js` first, then `html`? Or do so simultaneously?

Comment: ok sure that cant work if you have a static page you can work with the raltive position in the DOM like the first Child or the nthChild

Comment: yes, that's the case. The `html` is changed before changing `js`

Comment: @Opaldes, see if this example helps to explain my question better http://jsbin.com/qovamutewo/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

An approach which matches each call to `document.getElementById()` within `script` element, replaces the `id` within `script` element and at element itself with a random string generated by `URL.createObjectURL()`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var script = document.scripts[0];
  var ids = script.textContent.match(/document.getElementById\(.+\)/g);
  var _oldids = ids.toString()
                .replace(/document|\.getElementById|\(|\)|,/g, "")
                .split("");
  var _newids = [];
  _oldids.forEach(function(id) {
    var _id = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([]));
    URL.revokeObjectURL(_id);
    _id = _id.replace(/^blob\:.+\//g, "");
    _newids.push(_id);
    script.textContent = script.textContent
                         .replace(new RegExp('"' + id + '"'), '"' + _id + '"');
    document.getElementById(id).id = _id;
  });
  
  console.log(_oldids, _newids, document.documentElement.outerHTML); 
}
```

```html
<div id="a">a</div>
<div id="b">b</div>
<div id="c">c</div>
<script>
  var a = "a";
  var b = "b";
  var c = "c";
  document.getElementById(a).style.color = "blue";
  document.getElementById(b).style.color = "red";
  document.getElementById(c).style.color = "green";
</script>
```